# C : Using a do-while, the program does not stop to get the answer to the question which needs to be evaluated

Tags: c, do-while

In the below code just before the ending of the do-while loop, there is a question asked. The program does not stop to get input.

Request help so the program stops, gets the input from the user and then executes based on the input provided.

***Complete code below:***

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i; char p_cont= 'q';
    do
    {
        int f, f_ans=1;
        int p, num_2=2, p_int ;
        int eo=0 ;
        printf("\n\nPress 1 for Factorial of a number\n");
        printf("Press 2 for Prime or not\n");
        printf("Press 3 for Odd or even\nPress 4 for exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        fflush(stdin);

        switch(i)
        {
            case(1):
                printf("Enter the number: ");
                scanf("%d", &f);
                for(int f_inc=f; f_inc>0; f_inc--)
                    f_ans*=f_inc;
                printf("Factorial of %d is : %d\n", f, f_ans);
                fflush(stdin);
                break;
            case(2):
                printf("Enter a number to find out if its prime: ");
                scanf("%d", &p);
                if(p==num_2)
                    printf("%d is the smallest prime numer\n", p);
                else
                    for(p_int=2; p_int<p; p_int++)
                    {
                        if(p%p_int==0)
                        {
                            printf("%d is not a prime number\n", p);
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                            continue;
                    }
                    printf("%d is a prime number\n", p);
                    fflush(stdin);
                    break;
            case(3):
                printf("Enter a number to check if its EVEN or ODD: ");
                scanf("%d", &eo);
                if (eo%2==1)
                    printf("The number %d is ODD\n", eo);
                else
                    printf("The number %d is EVEN\n", eo);
                fflush(stdin);
                break;
        }


        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Do you wish to continue? Enter Y/N: ");
        scanf("%c", &p_cont);
        fflush(stdin);

    }while(p_cont=='y' || p_cont=='Y');
    printf("\n\n\nThanks for using the app! Come back for more calculations\n");
}
```

Comment: *fflush(stdin);* does nothing, replace *scanf("%c", &p_cont);* by *scanf(" %c", &p_cont);* (there is a space before '%') else you just read a newline from a previous input

Comment: Output the character you get from your `scanf("%c", &p_cont);`. Do so inside a "frame" of first printing a "#" then the character, then a "*". Then you will see that it is the return/linebreak from the previous scanf(). Which left something in the input because flushing input usually does not work as expected. Let me know wether I guessed correctly.

Comment: ^ this is your issue, I tested your code at the [online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) and added a `printf("%d", p_cont);` after the `scanf` and I got 10. So the issue is that you are reading the `Enter` keypress from before, which is ASCII character 10.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. `scanf` _does_ stop to take input, but input goes to a queue, and it will get any previously unprocessed input first. And you initially read a number, but the `Enter` press from before is nowhere read, so it is still in the queue, and your `%c` gets this `Enter` press as value 10 (and doesn't stop because it immediately got input, from the queue!). So please use one of the ways described in my link above, or in the comment by Yunnosch above or the answer by bruno below, to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix read of integer and read of a character at the end of your loop, when you want to read the char (theoretically y/n) in fact you read the newline ending a previous input for an *int* but not read when you read the *int* so still available and not removed as you supposed by *fflush(stdin)* because that one does nothing.

To flush the space including newline not yet read replace

```
scanf("%c", &p_cont);
```

by

```
scanf(" %c", &p_cont); /* note the space before % */
```

---

About *fflush* the manual says :

> For input streams associated with seekable files (e.g., disk files, but not pipes or terminals), fflush() discards any buffered data  that  has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been consumed by the       application.

*stdin* is not a disk file but terminal (supposing no redirection)

---

After remove the useless *fflush(stdin);* and adding the space in *scanf* your program (can) works:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out


Press 1 for Factorial of a number
Press 2 for Prime or not
Press 3 for Odd or even
Press 4 for exit
1
Enter the number: 5
Factorial of 5 is : 120
Do you wish to continue? Enter Y/N: y


Press 1 for Factorial of a number
Press 2 for Prime or not
Press 3 for Odd or even
Press 4 for exit
2
Enter a number to find out if its prime: 11
11 is a prime number
Do you wish to continue? Enter Y/N: y


Press 1 for Factorial of a number
Press 2 for Prime or not
Press 3 for Odd or even
Press 4 for exit
3
Enter a number to check if its EVEN or ODD: 67
The number 67 is ODD
Do you wish to continue? Enter Y/N: n



Thanks for using the app! Come back for more calculations
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

However warning, if a valid integer is not enter when you want one *scanf* doesn't set the receiver and later you use it not initialized, thank to the fact you also read a char you do not enter in an infinite loop where *scanf* never success. For instance enter yyyy rather than 1,2,3 or 4 and look at the execution.

I recommend you to always check the value returned by *scanf* to know if it was able to read the value(s)